# For loop to input values into a 2d array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter matrix 1: ");
for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
    for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
        a[row][col]=input.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Hi there - Given the above solution to entry of data into a 2d 3*3 array called `a`, I'm currently unable to take user input. The intellij ide won't accept any input that I can see at the point of `input.nextDouble()`.

I guess I'm missing something obvious but what ? :)

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: click in the console area to give it focus, then type numbers hitting enter after each number

Comment: clicking on the console doesn't permit any input. For example:

Enter matrix 1: < typing in any number here after returning focus to the console and pressing enter means that nothing happens.

I've tried placing the .nextInt() earlier and the same effect is true outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's JUNIT4 not taking console input - that's why changing focus to the console produces no result.

Answer (score 3):

The below code works perfectly for me

```
double a[][]=new double[3][3];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int row=0;row<3;row++){

            for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
                System.out.println("Enter value: ");
                a[row][col]=input.nextDouble();
            }
        }
```

Comment: it's a Junit problem - I wanted to use JUNIT4 to take user input but couldn't do so.